# Can I set JQuery to work WITHOUT noConflict option in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm definitely NOT using another library for my WP installation and I'm loading lots of external js files that rely on the use of $. So I need to load jQuery WITHOUT the non-conflict mode.

I've seen 3 different ways:

a) deregistering present Jquery script and registering mine, (without the .noConflict() call in the last line)

b) using this code (but I can't add all my js files there)

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
 })(jQuery);
```

c) just assigning

```
$ = jQuery
```

I'm not sure what the pros and cons are (I guess b method only works for in-line code, not for adding my own jquery based js files which expect $ to be available)

Please advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) make sure your 'own' version is compatible with wordpress.

c) make sure this statement is executed before including other jquery lib (the ones which expect `$`).

a and c) I won't do this for admin side

Comment: Thanks soju! So I can either use a) or c) ? 
(I don't need this for admin, only for front)